# React + Redux update accessToken by refreshToken and re-send all crash dispatch with new accessToken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this code to add accessToken to all request:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    function(config) {
        config.params = config.params || {};
        config.params.access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
        return config;
    },
    function(error) {
        // Do something with request error
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

And I have interceptor to check all **401** errors

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function(response) {
        return response;
    },
    function(error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            if (error.response.data.error === "invalid_token") {
                history.push("/login");
            } else if (error.response.data.error === "token_expired") {
                //self.props.dispatch(OauthAction.tokenExpired());
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

How can I get new access token by `refreshToken`, when token expired and resend all crash dispatch with new token?

For example, when this request is crash, I need to get new token and my function must again send request for update data on page:

```js
export function getNews() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(Config.DOMAIN + "news").then((response) => {
            dispatch(setNews(response.data));
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ? You want to be able to dispatch an action within the interceptor ?

Comment: I dont know what dispatch I must resend. And the place when I call this.props.dispatch(getNews().then((news)=> {console.log(news)}; ,
must work out again after update token